# how to sleep in for loop until finished loading page android

Tags: java, android, for-loop, webview

I am making an app to do something in webview automatically.

I want to make a pause between two lines inside (for-loop) until page finished loading without using Thread.sleep because it freezing my application.

this is my code:

```
    webview.loadUrl("http://**********");

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {


                for(int i=1;i<10;i++){

                         evaluateJavascript( "document.getElementById('select').value=" + i)
                         evaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('Search').click();")

                         //wait until finished loading
                         while( isloading() ){
                             try {
                                  Thread.sleep(1000);
                                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                  e.printStackTrace();
                                 }
                         }


                         evaluateJavascript( "document.getElementById('any_select').value=5")
                         .
                         .
                         .
                         .

                }




public boolean isloading(){
boolean isloading;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            webview.evaluateJavascript("(function() { return document.getElementById(\"Loading\").style.display; })();", new ValueCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
                    if(s.equals("none")){
                    isloading=false;
                    }else{
                    isloading=true;
                    }
                }
            });
    }
    if(isloading=true)return true;
    if(isloading=false)return false;


}
```

Comment: What about using `AsyncTask`?

Comment: how to use asynctask in this case? @Java_User

Comment: doInBackground cannot touch the UI.  @Java_User

Comment: Added an answer. Just check and let me know.

Comment: Asynctask will not solve your problem, because  you want to stop which is happening on UI thread, and Asynctask is a background approach

Comment: what can I do to solve the problem? @warlock

Comment: Please elaborate more ,what you are trying to achieve, so that we can help you out with that

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Thread.sleep then the alternative is to use AsyncTask in your application.

You can do your loading task in doInBackground() method of AsyncTask and call it using new AsyncTaskClass.execute();

You can go through it from here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: For UI you can display the ProgressDialog in method onPreExecute();

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar (instead of AsyncTask):

**Edit:**

```
Timer timer = new Timer();



while( isloading() ){
         try {
               timer.schedule( new TimerTask(){
              public void run() { 
                 //
                }
              }, delay);
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
             }
     }
```

Comment: Asynctask will not solve my problem, because i want to stop which is happening on UI thread, and Asynctask is a background approach   @Java_User

Comment: Edited my answer . You can try using `Timer`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve, what i understand, that once your second line is called  you want to stop  there and when after 1000 ms you want to continue. You can do one thing, copy all the code after your second line and put that in run method of below code:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() 
{
    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
}, 1000);
```

It will execute you code after 1000ms

Comment: Sometimes it takes a second and sometimes more than a second

Comment: it is not a perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute sequentially actions happening on UIThread and in backgrounds threads you should be looking for the Bolt Library by Parse/Facebook.

It apply Javascript promises to Android application.

You can go through it from here : https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android